# Ionic - Header icon is aligned to the top

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I made a custom font icon using [Fontastic](http://fontastic.me/) to use in my Ionic project. When I applied the icon to the header as a button, the alignment seems to be off. But whenever I changed the icon to an icon from [Ionicons](http://ionicons.com) it works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

I didn't apply any custom styles.

Here's what it looks like.

[image]

The icon on the right is the custom icon. And it's being aligned to the top whereas an icon from Ionicons doesn't.

EDIT: The code,

```
<ion-nav-title>Title</ion-nav-title>

<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
  <button class="button button-icon button-clear my-custom-icon-class" 
      ng-click="x.a">
  </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

EDIT 2:

I tried both line-height and vertical-align:middle.

Line-height does not change anything. And vertical-align by default is set to "top". Giving middle does not solve my problem and it breaks the ionic icons as well. Note I'm overriding ionic's CSS. As it is, Ionic icons are working just fine. It's my custom font that's breaking.

EDIT 3:

I'm wondering perhaps it has something to do with the SVG I created for making the font icon? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use `line-hight.`

you can use line height to vertically align your icon.

see this http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

NB: Sorry this is suppose to be a comment but I dont have enough reputation for that. :(

Comment: no problem, but can you make it more descriptive that will be better.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Thanks :) yes,  I will :)

Comment: Hi, I tried both. Line-height and vertical-align and it doesn't give the output I want. I made an edit to my question explaining the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `vertical_align: middle;`. Look here [vertical-align | W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

Comment: Both vertical align and line height doesn't work. Vertical-align by default is given as "top" and changing it to "middle" is breaking the icons given by the ionic framework. So it's not the best solution. :( Right now only my custom icons are breaking.

Answer (score 0):

line-height is your option. Use firebug to see what suits you best.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp